# Is changing contextLifetime to Singleton a correct solution to fix the following error?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am using Asp.net Core 2. Consider the following classes:

```
public class BlogDbContext: DbContext
{
 .....
}

public interface IBlogData { ... }

public class BlogData : IBlogData
{
    private BlogDbContext _context;
    public BlogData(BlogDbContext context) { ... }
    .......
}
```

When I used the default value `contextLifetime: ServiceLifetime.Scoped` as follows,

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{

   .....

   services.AddDbContext<BlogDbContext>(...);

   .....

   services.AddSingleton<IBlogData, BlogData>();
}
```

Compilation, first migration and first database update were performed without any error. But I got the following error when visiting the page for the first time.

> InvalidOperationException: Cannot consume scoped service 'MyProject.Data.BlogDbContext' from singleton 'MyProject.Services.IBlogData'.

## Question

Is it correct if I fix the error by changing `contextLifetime` as follows ?

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{

   .....

   services.AddDbContext<BlogDbContext>(...,contextLifetime: ServiceLifetime.Singleton);

   .....

   services.AddSingleton<IBlogData, BlogData>();
}
```

Note: this problem is specific to Asp.Net Core 2.0.

Comment: I think the better solution would be to use `AddScoped` for your `IBlogData`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you should generally always used scoped for DbContext in asp.net core that way it gets created once per request and is automatically disposed for you at the end of the request.

You are not really showing the code where the error is happening, but my guess is it is happening because you are running some code in startup to run the migrations. If you confirm that or show the code where the error is actually happening I could offer more help

Comment: I compile the project, do the first migration and database update. Everything just works fine. But when I visit the page, I got the above error.

Comment: still your question should show the code where the error happens. If you are using dbcontext inside some other service class that class also needs to be scoped

Answer (score 2):

It's because you are trying to use a scoped service from a singleton service.
This is new to asp.net core 2.0. Only singleton services can be consumed by a 
 signleton service.
You need to add BlogData as Scoped.

Answer (score 1):

Old question without a great answer.

The reason you get this error is because a scoped service has to be recreated every time a new page request is made (Atleast within ASP.net). How it does that is everytime a service is "requested" by way of injection (For example within a constructor), it caches the first time it's requested, then for subsequent requests, it simply returns that same instance. At the end of the page load, it trashes this instance.

Now a singleton is instead cached that first time it's requested, but it's never disposed. Every request ever made for the service will return the exact same instance.

The problem is if you have a parent service that is singleton that then references a child service that is scoped. That first request, the parent and child are created. The second request, well the parent is a singleton so it isn't recreated. Now we have a problem, because the child service is scoped, how can it be created for each request if the thing that is requesting it (And thus kicking off the DI), is a singleton? It can't. So an exception is thrown.

Interestingly, it is more about saving yourself from hanging yourself more than anything. For example, if you replace the scoped instance with a transient one, you will still have the same "problem", but it won't throw an exception.

More info here if you need further examples : https://dotnetcoretutorials.com/2018/03/20/cannot-consume-scoped-service-from-singleton-a-lesson-in-asp-net-core-di-scopes/